# Quando usar Random.Shared do .NET 6?

Tags: c#, .net, random

Quando seria vantajoso utilizar o `Random.Shared` que veio com o .NET 6 ao invés das abordagens normalmente utilizadas, ou quando eu não deveria usá-lo?

Comment: a vantagem do `Random.Shared` é ser mult-thread safe [segundo a documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.shared?view=net-6.0), logo qualquer cenário que seja mult-thread e partilhe o objeto `Random` seria vantajoso ao invés de implementar manualmente um `lock` por exemplo para proteger o objeto `Random`

Comment: é o mesmo conceito de fazer um `x++` numa variável usada num código mult-thread, precisaria proteger isso com um `lock`, mas pode usar o `Interlocked.Increment` que já faz isso :)

Comment: @RicardoPontual o que eu posso estudar para entender direito como isso funciona?

Comment: para estudar a fundo não conheço, mas tem um da serie "boas práticas" no MSDN que trata de *thread safe* que é bem interessante: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/managed-threading-best-practices